# How to close tab in Incognito mode in javascript

Tags: javascript

how can I close a tab in incognito mode in chrome? I'm using `window.close()`, which is working in Chrome but not in Incognito mode. I searched a lot and cannot find the proper answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does work for me. Specify your version/how you're calling the function.

Comment: Hi @user202729, I'm using it in react v16. It neither shows any console error.

Comment: Include a [example].

Comment: I mean Chrome version.

Comment: I'm using ```Version 93.0.4577.82 (Official Build) (64-bit)```

Comment: Did you create the incognito window from script? You can't close windows that are created by the end user. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close

Comment: @skyline3000 I'm manually opening the incognito, is there no way to close the tab if not opened by script?

Comment: Please read "This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method."

Comment: You cannot close windows that are not created by script. It states so clearly in the docs "This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the Window.open() method. If the window was not opened by a script, an error similar to this one appears in the console: Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script." It wouldn't be a very good user experience if a website could just close the windows/tabs you open...